# withEndAction() triggering onEndAnimation() function?

Tags: android, listview

This is my code (simplified)

```
public class StockAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Stock> implements Animator.AnimatorListener
{
    //Global variable - StockAdapter adapter;
    //Global varaiable - View animatingView;
     View.OnTouchListener stockRowOnTouch=new View.OnTouchListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
             switch (action) {
                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                   //code to get the cordintated\s
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // get the coodinates
                    if(row is swiped) //determined by the coordinates
                    {
                      animatingView=view;
                      view.animate().translationX(itemWidth).alpha(1).setDuration(500).setListener(adapter);

    }
}

 @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
 animatingView.setTranslationX(0);
        animatingView.animate().alpha(0.4f).setDuration(4000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //After the animation duration delete the stock


            }
        });
}
}
```

**What I am trying to Do**

1. When a row is swiped far enough, an animation is done wherein it is
   translated off the window in 500 miliseconds.
2. After that duration the the row(view) is again translated back into
   the window and some changes are made into the view.
3. Then another animation is run for 4 seconds wherein the view has to
   fade in that duration. After the 4 seconds I am deleting that row
   from the list view and calling `notifydatasetchanged()`.

   **How am I doing it**
4. For the first animation (translate the row off the window in 500
   milliseconds) I have set a listener - the `StockAdapter` class
   object itself.
5. Then in the `onAnimationEnd()` function I have translated the view
   back to it's original position and then run the fade animation but
   this time used the `withEndAction`.

**What is happening**

1. On swiping, the 1st animation runs perfectly and it enters the
   `onAnimationEnd()`function and the changes made to the view are
   visible.
2. Then the fade animation also starts running (`withEndAction()`) and
   after 4 seconds the row is deleted from the listview and it is
   refreshed.
3. Now this animation keeps on running till there are no data to be put in that position

On verifying the logs it looks like `withEndAction()` seems to be triggering the `onEndAnimation()`. Is this some kind of a bug?

**NOTE**
I checked out the source code of [View](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java), [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/37047293/) and [ViewRootImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java#ViewRootImpl.RunQueue.0mActions). It doesn't suggest that withEndAction invokes the same listener again. If I am wrong can someone please point me out where it does that? The function invocations stop in the `postDelayed()` method of `RunQueue` class of `ViewRootImpl`.

Comment: you animate each view.  Even though it should only run once, you made each view (in some cases, reused views) run the animation.  TO make it run only once on one view, you might have a flag per row that each row interrogates whether it should have an animation set or not

Comment: @Martin : I forgot to mention that the animation is done only when the row is swiped. Have edited the code. So even if the row is reused again, the animation should take place only if the row is swiped right

Comment: how do you determine "if(the row is swiped) { "  ?   If that doesn't differentiate this row from every other row you will see the animation more than once.

Comment: @Martin I determine that by the row number that the user has swiped on. But after the swipe the data is deleted (see the end action). But even if the same view is used again, why is the animation again running? I have not set a repeating animation or something

Comment: @Martin : Have I got it wrong  - IF there is a swipe, I take the view and make it animate with a particular end action. Is it expected behavior if that view starts animating each time it is displayed on the activity after that. How does this thing animation thing work.

Comment: Since List views will be reused, once animation ends set the alpha of view to 1. `public void run() { // remove from adapter & notify data set changed. view.setAlpha(1); }`. Try and let me know whether it solves the issue.

Comment: @ManishMulimani I have already tried that manish. I set the alpha go 1, then cancel the animation using view.animate().cancel()... But still I get the strange behavior

Comment: Do you want to give a try to this [devbytes implementation](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.in/2013/06/devbytes-animating-listview-deletion.html)?

Comment: @ManishMulimani : yeah I have already seen that. And he doesn't even use teh cancel function and it works for him. But I am not sure why it is happening to me. My implementation is slightly different. In that the view that I am using is a custom view. i.e it extends LinearLayout. Do I have to override some method for animation or anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the animation listener in your `onAnimationEnd()` to avoid triggering the same listener you've previously set in `onTouchListener()`.
It is not clear from the official documentation, but `View.animate()` will try to reuse the same `ViewPropertyAnimator` for your view, including the listener you previously set.

The code below should do the trick:

```
...
animatingView.animate().alpha(0.4f).setDuration(4000).setListener(null).withEndAction(...)
...
```

Comment: I have not yet tried your solution. Will try it and let you know. But I went through the source code to check if what you are telling is true i.e View.animate() tries to reuse the same ViewPropertyAnimator??  I have edited the post. Please check the 'NOTE' section.

Comment: You should take a look at the `View.animate()` sourcecode instead. https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L18437 As you can see the same ViewPropertyAnimator will be reused on the next `animate()` and in your case you previously set a listener - that is completely separated from `withEndAction()`

Comment: Your solution works. And yeah it uses the same viewPropertyAnimator object. But still it is unclear where exactly why withEndAction() execution sets of the onEndAnimation and also where is the exact code which executes the runnable? I will accept your answer cos the solution works but it is all still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

**problem:**

```
.setListener(adapter)
```

Since you used the `Animator.AnimatorListener` to the `animatingView's ViewPropertyAnimator`  after 4 seconds it will execute your `withEndAction` **but after** remember the listener you set to the `animatingView`, there is your problem it will execute the `onAnimationEnd` again and again because you are using the **same reference** to the `ViewPropertyAnimator`  from your `animatingView`.

**solution:**

You need to cancel the animation inside your `withEndAction` after you deleted the row to prevent it to call again the **interface methods** all over again.

**sample:**

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
 animatingView.setTranslationX(0);
        animatingView.animate().alpha(0.4f).setDuration(4000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //After the animation duration delete the stock
                animatingView.animate().cancel(); //will cancel the animation and listener

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I had already tried that. But the problem is that as soon as the end action is called, the onEndAnimation is called. Cancelling it inside the end action will only ensure that it is not called for the 3rd time. But it would have already called it the second time and the onEndAnimation would have started execution

Comment: @Ashwin sorry it sopposed to be before you animate under setTranslationX to clear the underlying options to the VPA and to start a whole new animation again